# can not type cast @selector expression when using setAction:(SEL)@selector(start:)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I'm reading a project code from others, it could be compiled successfully in 32bit, but when I  switch the project to 64bit, there is one error message just like the title said.

code:

```
[obj setAction:(SEL)@selector(start:)];
```

I know the return value type of `@selector` is `SEL` and the parameter of `setAction` needs a `SEL` args, but why it failed in 64bit?  What's the `SEL` type actually?

Thanks!

Comment: `@selector` isn't a function, so it doesn't have a “return value type”. `@selector(start:)` is a literal, just like `0.0` or `@"foo"` or `(NSRect){ { 20.0, 20.0 }, { 640.0, 480.0 } }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not fail, but you don't need the cast at all. `@selector()` expressions are already of type `SEL`. Just write

```
[obj setAction:@selector(start:)];
```

The SEL type is, in terms of C, `struct objc_selector *`. On OS X and iOS, it is, however? backed by a plain `const char *`, which is unified by the linker and the kernel during loading time.